# Call a Method while Binding Datagrid Column WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

In my asp.net GridView I use to Convert a GridView Column Data in the following Way.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lb_gvInbox_DelTime" runat="server" Text='<%# this.GetTimeFormat(Eval("Order_Date"))%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And the Method will be

```
protected string GetTimeFormat(object dateTimeObj)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)dateTimeObj;
        return (dateTime.Date == time.Date) ? dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                : (dateTime.Year == time.Year) ? dateTime.ToString("MMM dd") : dateTime.ToString("dd/MMM/yy");
    }
```

How can I do like this in WPF DataGrid ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are [value converters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx).

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Order_Date, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatter}}" />

class DateFormatter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      // your code 
    }
}
```